# C- Floating point precision

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

I have a program:

```
int main() 
{   
        float f = 0.0f;  
        int i;  

        for (i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) 
                f = f + 0.1f; 

        if (f == 1.0f) 
                printf("f is 1.0 \n"); 
        else 
                printf("f is NOT 1.0\n"); 

        return 0; 
}
```

It always prints `f is NOT 1.0`. I understand this is related to floating point precision in C. But I am not sure exactly where it is getting messed up. Can someone please explain me why it is not printing the other line?

Comment: You've answered the question yourself. It's related to precision. Google will give you 1000.001 explanations.

Answer (score 6):

Binary floating point cannot represent the value 0.1 exactly, because its binary expansion does not have a finite number of digits (in exactly the same way that the decimal expansion of 1 ÷ 7 does not).

The binary expansion of 0.1 is

```
0.000110011001100110011001100...
```

When truncated to IEEE-754 single precision, this is approximately `0.100000001490116119` in decimal.  This means that each time you add the "nearly 0.1" value to your variable, you accumulate a small error - so the final value is slightly higher than `1.0`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compare floats like this. You need to define a threshold and compare based on that. [This](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/?p=89) blog post explains

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I went through the link and found this other link which explained to me what i was missing. http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Answer (score 3):

This is equivelent to adding 0.33 together 3 times (0.99) and wondering why it is not equal to 1.0.

You may wish to read [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 2):

For floating point numbers you should always use an epsilon value when comparing them:

```
#define EPSILON 0.00001f

inline int floatsEqual(float f1, float f2)
{
    return fabs(f1 - f2) < EPSILON; // or fabsf
}
```

Comment: Richard, +1 since I prefer self-contained answers but the function you're looking for is `fabs` rather than `abs` - I fixed that for you :-)

Comment: Thank you. This helps and explains a lot.

Comment: Downvoted for misleading *"should always use"*. Using epsilon comparison gives inconsistent results on float value range. On extreme values comparison is only an inefficient `==`. Epsilon comparison can be useful sometimes, but only sometimes.