# addition float values with 3 decimal points

Tags: c, double, addition

I have 2 float values as

```
A = 0.0306880000
B = 0.0396640000
```

When I use printf to print as `"%5.3f"`, A value is printed as `0.031` and B values is printed as `0.040`. When I add the two values together, I get the answer `0.070` (which is 0.0306880000 +  0.0396640000).

How do I include only 3 decimal points to be taken in to the addition so that the answer would be `0.071` (0.031 + 0.040).

Comment: That is not possible, in general, with floating point types.

Comment: do you mean the answer should be 0.069 when i add the 0.0306880000 and 0.0396640000 do a printf with %5.3f?

Comment: No. That is not related to what I said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C- Floating point precision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577179/c-floating-point-precision)

Comment: @MuertoExcobito The post you flagged as a duplicate is related to the issue, but is in no way an actual duplicate.

Comment: @2501 sry i did not get you

Answer (score -1):

You should round the value of A and B using this macro:

`#define ROUND3(number) ( (int)( (number) * 1000 + 0.5 ) / 1000.0 )`

[test code](http://ideone.com/hjnGMK)

Comment: This fail for many negative numbers, values outside the `int` range, values that round when adding 0.5 and some other cases.